offloading to helper function the buildup of where statements in sql query in drizzle
I have a helper function that I will utilize in drizzle to build dynamic queries, like this:
export async function dynamicQuery<T extends PgSelect>(
  qb: T,
  conditional_columns: colParams,
  table: string
) {
  const filters = Object.entries(conditional_columns)
    .filter(([, value]) => value !== undefined)
    .map(([key, value]) => {
      if (typeof value === "string" && value.includes(",")) {
        const valueArray = value.split(",").map((val) => val.trim());
        return inArray(sql.raw(`${table}.${key}`), valueArray);
      } else {
        return eq(sql.raw(`${table}.${key}`), value);
      }
    });

  return qb.where(and(...filters));
}

The problem is that I am trying to abstract even the table name for this and having a string in the parameters doe snot sound like a good idea to, introduces a bunch of hidden errors when utilizing the function in another query like:
  const base_query = db
    .select({
      host: osDb.host,
      it_service: osDb.itService,
    })
    .from(osDb)
    .where(eq(osDb.cmsTechType, "Database"))
    .limit(ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    .offset(offset)
    .$dynamic();

  const conditionalQuery = await dynamicQuery(
    base_query,
    conditional_columns,
    "os_dbg"
  );

My database table name is not os_dbg but os_db and this will not be spotted in typescript, hidden errors. Additionally this code is ommited .where(eq(osDb.cmsTechType, "Database")) when the query gets executed , maybe because of multiple where statements. What is the best appoach to have an abstract function and still be able to add where statements on top of the dynamic ones. Is there another approach other than dynamic in drizzle that can accomplish this?
